# Flexbox in nav bar: Can't align-items vertically

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm really new to html and css, so this is my first full attempt at making a nav bar, items in nav bar stuck to the top of the page, please tell me where things went wrong

https://codepen.io/galia-s/pen/GRojmwV

```
.flex-content {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto 3.25rem;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `align-content`, you might be looking at `align-items`, depending on what you are trying to achieve. I assume you want to center these items.

So your `.flex-content` class could look like this:

```
.flex-content {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    height: 5rem; //set height here instead of header
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've specified height for only header's flex-content and it worked!

Comment: Glad to hear. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You posted way too little information for a reliable answer, but anyway: To get flex-items to stack vertically, you have to add `flex-direction: column;` to the flex container.